# use of alternation "|" in sed's regex

Tags: regex, sed

I am using sed, GNU sed version 4.2.1.
I want to use the alternation "|" symbol in a subexpression.
For example :

```
echo "blia blib bou blf" | sed 's/bl\(ia|f\)//g'
```

should return

```
" blib bou "
```

but it returns

```
"blia blib bou blf".
```

How can I have the expected result ?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The "|" also needs a backslash to get its special meaning.

```
echo "blia blib bou blf" | sed 's/bl\(ia\|f\)//g'
```

will do what you want.

As you know, if all else fails, read the manual :-).

*GNU sed user's manual*, section [3.3 Overview of Regular Expression Syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions):

> `REGEXP1\|REGEXP2'
>
> Matches either REGEXP1 or REGEXP2.

Note the backslash...

Unfortunately, regex syntax is not really standardized... there are many variants, which differ among other things in which "special characters" need \ and which do not. In some it's even configurable or depends on switches (as in GNU `grep`, which you can switch between three different regex dialects).

This answer in particular is for [GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/). There are other `sed` variants, for example the one used in the BSDs, which behave differently.

Comment: For anyone else confused by this answer \| only works in gnu sed (gsed on os x) not vanilla sed (sed on os x).

Comment: @AndrewHancox Thank you so much! I was about to rip all of the hair out of my head (and so far I'm doing pretty good compared to my manager on the hair-front) - I know I know RegEx enough to try | and \| but I never thought about the fact that OSX might actually use a non-gnu sed.

Comment: The standard BSD/OS X version of `sed` does support alternation, but only with "extended" regex syntax (`-E`) - which means no backslashes on either the pipes or the parentheses: `echo "blia blib bou blf" | sed -E 's/bl(ia|f)//g'`

Comment: I edited my answer to note that it's for GNU sed only.

Answer (score 28):

Since there are several comments regarding non-Gnu `sed` implementations: At least on OS X, you can use the `-E` argument to `sed`:

> Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).  The re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats.

Then you can use regular expression metacharacters without escaping them. Example:

```
$ echo "blia blib bou blf" | sed -E 's/bl(ia|f)//g'
 blib bou
```

Answer (score 15):

GNU sed also supports the `-r` option (extended regular expressions). This means you don't have to escape the metacharacters:

```
echo foohello barhello | sed -re "s/(foo|bar)hello/hi/g"
```

Output:

```
hi hi
```

Comment: Yes, `-r` option is really really helpful for the readability of the expressions. That should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

The `\|` does not work with sed on Solaris 10 either. What I did was use

```
perl -p -e 's/bl(ia|f)//g'
```

Comment: +1 for portability since, if a system has perl, it will always use this syntax, unlike sed.

Answer (score 4):

Followup: sed -E allows it on MacOS. No backslash need for |.

```
 sed -E 's/this|orthat/oooo/g' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

In the GnuWin32 on Windows sed the syntax is `sed "s/thing1\|thing2/ /g" source > destination`.

The quotes must of type `"` - this is "Required" for the command to be parsed.